# Is there a way to refactor this Javascript for loop?

Tags: javascript, refactoring

This is a test project I'm using to learn Javascript in.  I have a for loop with if statements after that, that go into innerHTML's. Here is a for loop below.  I'm wondering if how I can do this with say map()?  I've looked online on how to use maps() but nothing shows stuff that's a little more complex then beginner understanding...which I'm a beginner.

```
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        let dataTitle = data[i].title;
        let dataTimeFrames = data[i].timeframes.daily;

        if (dataTitle === 'Work') {
            hours_work.innerHTML = `<p>${dataTimeFrames.current}hrs</p>`;
            past_work.innerHTML = `<p>Yesterday - ${dataTimeFrames.previous}hrs</p>`;
        }
        if (dataTitle === 'Study') {
            hours_play.innerHTML = `<p>${dataTimeFrames.current}hrs</p>`;
            past_play.innerHTML = `<p>Yesterday - ${dataTimeFrames.previous}hrs</p>`;
        }
        if (dataTitle === 'Play') {
            hours_study.innerHTML = `<p>${dataTimeFrames.current}hrs</p>`;
            past_study.innerHTML = `<p>Yesterday - ${dataTimeFrames.previous}hrs</p>`;
        }
        if (dataTitle === 'Exercise') {
            hours_exercise.innerHTML = `<p>${dataTimeFrames.current}hrs</p>`;
            past_exercise.innerHTML = `<p>Yesterday - ${dataTimeFrames.previous}hrs</p>`;
        }
        if (dataTitle === 'Social') {
            hours_social.innerHTML = `<p>${dataTimeFrames.current}hrs</p>`;
            past_social.innerHTML = `<p>Yesterday - ${dataTimeFrames.previous}hrs</p>`;
        }
        if (dataTitle === 'Self Care') {
            hours_care.innerHTML = `<p>${dataTimeFrames.current}hrs</p>`;
            past_care.innerHTML = `<p>Yesterday - ${dataTimeFrames.previous}hrs</p>`;
        }
    }
```

This code works just fine, I just want to learn how to refactor something like this.

Here is the repo for further understanding if you want: https://github.com/tmerrick17/time-tracking-dashboard

Comment: The loop keeps trying to overwrite the same two things. Why would `.map()` be appropriate in that case?

Comment: One simple thing you can do is update all but the first `if` statements to `else if` so they aren't all checked on every loop.

Comment: either you can use ```Switch Case```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the first thing I would do is instead of having your elements already determined and then setting their html, you can have a function that grabs the right element based on the title, so I imagine you have something like this:

```js
var hours_care = document.getElementById("hours_care")
```

instead, have a function that grabs the right elements based off the title. Something like this would be good:

```js
function getHoursAndPast (title) {
  var lowerTitle = title.toLowerCase();
  var hours = document.getElementById("hours_" + lowerTitle)
  var past = document.getElementById("past_" + lowerTitle)
  return [hours, past]
}
```

This function returns an array of the elements you're trying to get. You can then take that and DE-structure this array inside your loop. I wouldn't use map, because you're not interested in getting an array back from this. Instead, use `forEach`

```js
data.forEach(datum => {
  let dataTitle = datum.title;
  let dataTimeFrames = datum.timeframes.daily;
  const [hours, past] = getHoursAndPast(dataTitle);
  hours.innerHTML = `<p>${dataTimeFrames.current}hrs</p>`;
  past.innerHTML = `<p>Yesterday - ${dataTimeFrames.previous}hrs</p>`;
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your feedback.  I was able to successfully use this...much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to create an object that holds the references to the HTML elements. This breaks up the data specific information from the loop making it easier to manage. Of course, you're still left dealing with the somewhat lengthy dataObj, which isn't ideal.

```
const dataObj = {
  Work: {
    hoursElement: document.getElementById('hours_work'),
    pastElement: document.getElementById('past_work'),
  },
  Study: {
    hoursElement: document.getElementById('hours_study'),
    pastElement: document.getElementById('past_study'),
  }
  // Etc....
}

for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  let dataTitle = data[i].title;
  let dataTimeFrames = data[i].timeframes.daily;

  dataObj[dataTitle].hoursElement.innerHTML = `<p>${dataTimeFrames.current}hrs</p>`;
  dataObj[dataTitle].pastElement.innerHTML = `<p>Yesterday - ${dataTimeFrames.previous}hrs</p>`;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using some [data-*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*) instead of ids would simplify your task a lot.

Given this HTML sample (found on your GitHub):

```html
<!-- Social Card -->
<div class="card-social">
  <div class="card-top card-img">
    <img src="public/images/icon-social.svg" alt="book icon">
  </div>
  <a class="card-bot-anchor" href="#">
    <div class="card-bot card__info">
      <h2>Social</h2>
      <img src="public/images/icon-ellipsis.svg" alt="3 dots icon">
      <p id="hours-social" data-title="Self Care" data-timeframe="current" class="hours-current margin-top1">hrs</p>
      <p id="past-social" data-title="Self Care" data-timeframe="previous"  class="past-toggle">Category Toggle</p>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Notice the addons

```html
data-title="Self Care" data-timeframe="current"
```

Your loop would be

```
data.forEach(activity => {
  let r = activity.title,
    t = activity.timeframes.daily;

  document.querySelector(`[data-title='${r}'][data-timeframe='current']`).innerHTML = `<p class="hours-current">${t.current}hrs</p>`);
  document.querySelector(`[data-title='${r}'][data-timeframe='previous']`).innerHTML = `<p>Yesterday - ${t.previous}hrs</p>`;
}
```

And most likely you can discard the ids and the bunch of variables created for them.